# Why this line wouldn't be printed? (C++ threads)

Tags: c++, multithreading

Found this example in the net and can't find out why this line wouldn't be printed

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main() 
{
     pid_t return_value;

     printf("Forking process\n");
     return_value=fork();
     printf("The process id is %d
       and return value is %d\n",
       getpid(), return_value);
     execl("/bin/ls/","ls","-l",NULL);
     printf("This line is not printed\n");
}
```

Comment: Have you read docs for all the functions involved before asking? Like what `execl` does? And BTW, `fork` creates a process, not a thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A successful `execl` never returns, see the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl):

> The exec() functions only return if an error has occurred.

Instead, the host process is replaced by what you are `exec`ing, in this case, the `ls` process image:

> The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image.

This way, your program will be replaced in memory before reaching the last `printf` statement, causing it to never execute.

Answer (score 1):

`exec*()` functions is a special in sense that they are **non-returning**. Typical implementation of that function "replaces" modules of current process that is effectively the same as starting of new program right inside of current process. In your case new program is `/bin/ls`. During `execl()` all previous images are unloaded from process, then `/bin/ls` and all its dependencies are loaded and control is passed to entry point of `/bin/ls`, that calls its `main()` function, so on.

Thus there is no place to return control after `execl()` since module that calls it no more exists in address space of current process.